# How to add attribute to the xml node?

Tags: php, xml

I generating following xml in php.

PHP Code :-

```
header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>";
echo "<Response>";
echo "<Dial>";
echo  $client_no;
echo "</Dial>";
echo "<Say>The call failed or the remote party hung up. Goodbye.</Say>";
echo "</Response>";
```

Output :-

```
<Response>
  <Dial>919880022477</Dial>
  <Say>
      The call failed or the remote party hung up. Goodbye.
  </Say>
</Response>
```

now i want to add attribute to the Dial node.
something like :-

```
<Dial callerId="jitu">919880022477</Dial>
```

Comment: Did you put any effort into figuring it out yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
echo "<Dial callerID='jitu'>";
```